# How to Return all Resultset value from method. Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a database that contains:

```
title of the show:
Avenger
Deadpool
etc.
```

And I have a method that gets all the title of the show

```
    public String shows2(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ticket","root",null);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from events");  
        while(rs.next()){
            String title = rs.getString("title");
            return "Shows: " +title;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "something";
}
```

But when I use this method it only returns one row/show

```
"Shows: Avenger"
```

Comment: You can only return from a method once.

Comment: Save your `ResultSet` as a `List` of some sort.

Comment: Statements in your while loop execute only once because you return from the method immediately. Based on what you need you should either save the Strings in a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) [(Jenkov tutorial)](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/list.html) or print them (without returning). Also I strongly suggest you look into [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to return a `List<String>` instead of a single `String`.

```
public List<String> shows2(){
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ticket","root",null);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from events");  
        while(rs.next()){
            String title = rs.getString("title");
            result.add(title);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `public String shows2(){` to `public List<String> shows2(){` so you can then return a full list of results

And don't return in the `while` loop, instead add to your `List`, e.g. `yourList.add(title);` and then return at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

```
    public ArrayList<String> shows2() {
    ArrayList<String> movieList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ticket", "root", null);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from events");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String title = rs.getString("title");
            movieList.add("Shows: " + title);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return movieList;
}
```